# How could I tell from a observed oscillation frequency to determine if it is caused by the instability of the control system or not?

Tags: controls, stability

I have a control loop to control the vehicle on the centerline with a bandwidth of 2 rad/s, and I saw the vehicle keeps oscillating around the centerline in a sinusoid whose period is around 8 to 10 seconds; how could I tell that if the oscillation can indicate that the controller have instability issue? Or in anther word, if the controller has the instability issue, what its oscillation frequency should be?